# RevalidatePath won't work unless export const dynamic is set to auto

Tags: next.js

I am facing a very strange problem on my next 13 app. By default dynamic auto rule is enabled. However, In my case it won't work, or re-create the static pages unless I include this rule. I am on the latest stable Next 13 version. Is someone else having this same issue? Not sure if it is a bug but if I don't include this revalidatePath won't work or show me the new page data from my headless CMS

```
export const dynamic = "auto"
```